# How to make newly inserted row in Excel include automatically generated data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have an excel sheet that I am using as a requirements document. The sheet that I am looking at is using the following numbering sequence in `A`: FR01, FR02, FR03. The sheet may be sorted by other fields.

When a new row is created, no matter where it is generated within the sheet, I would like the cell in `A` to be populated by the next number in the FRxx sequence. If the highest value in `A` is FR55, I'd like FR56. I have tried various formulas and number schemes, but can't seem to get it right.

Thanks for your help!

[image: Image of portion of sorted sheet]

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your workbook or a sample of data to help us better understand your question. (You can paste an image from PrintScreen/Snipping tool directly into your post)

Comment: How are the FR numbers being generated *now*?

Comment: The FR numbers are being entered manually now. I'm adding an image of a portion of the worksheet as well to the original post.

Comment: "The problem that I am running into is that after sorting, the automatic numbering system no longer functions" but "The FR numbers are being entered manually now." So... the problem is with the automatic numbering system, and the problem with it is that it has never existed? What does the image demonstrate? What does a solution to this problem look like?

Comment: I guess by automatic numbering, I meant using the fill or flashfill function. My thought here is that there should be a simple solution to this problem that I just haven't identified through the research I've done. The image gives you an idea of the layout of the sheet looks like. I thought I was pretty clear about what a solution would look like, but I'll give it another shot. When a new row is created, no matter where it is generated within the sheet, I would like the cell in column A to be populated by the next number in the FRxx sequence. If the highest Req number is FR55, I'd like FR56.

Comment: Got it. I've taken the liberty of editing your question (and title) to reflect the nature of the actual request, then. Please feel free to roll back or revise it yourself, of course. I've also added the VB tag, as this is going to require VB to accomplish. Having newly created rows include dynamic data cannot be done with a worksheet function.

Comment: Thanks! I overestimated what Excel could do. I haven't looked into VB solutions, as I haven't worked with them in the past. This should be a great learning opportunity to grow my excel skills as I start using it more frequently.

Comment: So if I understand correctly: If I right click Row 3, Click Insert, you want the newly inserted blank row (which would start at A3) to automatically populate cell A3 with an FRxx number, where xx is one increment higher than the largest FRxx number (so if the biggest one is FR55, A3 becomes FR56)?

Comment: @user2800 that is correct. Alex M edited the original post to better represent my request. Sounds like this will require a VB script.

Comment: Yes, you will need VBA. If you want to simplify the code, you can create a formula somewhere in your workbook that identifies what FRxx code will come next. Then when you create your macro, all you need your code to do is insert a new row at a position of your choosing and copy the result of that formula into the first column.

Comment: @user2800 Yep. I was thinking the same. That formula could be `="FR"&MAX(VALUE(MID(INDIRECT("$A2:$A"&COUNTA(A:A)),3,2)))+1` entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter. That tells you what the number *should* be. Still, to plonk data into a new row would require, at minimum, a macro.

Comment: In fact, @Endro, since you seem receptive to adding skills, I'm gonna make that my quasi-answer for you: Stick the formula I just wrote somewhere in your workbook. Google "Excel record macro" and read a couple of tutorials. From there it should be pretty easy to complete your task. If you really want to cross all your i's, write up your solution as an answer to this question, and after a day or two you can accept your own answer. @ me in the comments and I'll upvote, too. This is a very useful skill and a perfect example use case.

Comment: @AlexM After placing the formula in the workbook I have found a few things. '="FR"&MAX(VALUE(MID(INDIRECT("$A2:$A"&COUNTA(A:A)),3,2)))+1' DOES produce the next available FRxx if column A is sorted a-z AND there are no blank rows inserted. Once a row is inserted, or a sort is activated the formula breaks and displays #VALUE!, noting an error. Once the row is removed, the formula works again. I'm going to keep toying around with it. Once this process is figured out, I'll be able to implement it to all of my requirements docs / share it with others. Thanks for the help!

Comment: 1. Ah, you're right of course that inserting a blank value will break it. `MAX` balks at evaluating an array including a #VALUE error. Let me think... 2. Also, it occurs to me that `COUNTA` is insufficiently robust, for a similar reason; let's use `="FR"&MAX(VALUE(MID(INDIRECT("$A2:$A"&LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A<>""),ROW(A:A))),3,2))+1)`
3. sorting of column `A` doesn't make any difference either way, with any version of the formula, though

Comment: Here we go. Took me a bit to figure out the right spot to put the `IFERROR` to get what we needed. `="FR"&MAX(IFERROR(VALUE(MID(INDIRECT("$A2:$A"&LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A<>""),ROW(A:A))),3,2)),0))+1` This works irrespective of sorting and regardless of how many blank rows might be inserted.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind, my partial solution based on our discussion in the comments became interesting enough to me that I'd like to post it as an answer for posterity, even though I haven't gotten you all the way there yet.

The solution you're looking for has two parts; I've solved the first and, per our discussion, will leave the second to you.

### Part I

Put this formula anywhere in your workbook:

`="FR"&TEXT(MAX(IFERROR(VALUE(MID(INDIRECT("$A2:$A"&LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A<>""),ROW(A:A))),3,2)),0))+1,"00")`

This is an array formula; confirm it after entry by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

This will create a cell containing the 'FR' ID that should be assigned to the next-created record:

[image]

Some notes on this formula:

1. `LOOKUP` is a fun thing. This trick to use it to locate the last-filled row or column is very cool. Originally I had `="FR"&TEXT(MAX(IFERROR(VALUE(MID(INDIRECT("$A2:$A"&COUNTA(A:A)),3,2)),0))+1,"00")` but `COUNTA` is not reliable when blanks exist. I include it here because the comparison between that version and the final one helps to demonstrate what's doing what in that long-ish formula.
   1.5 I suppose I should include a shout out to excel jet dot net, from which the `LOOKUP` chunk of code here is taken directly.
2. Other than the `LOOKUP` trick inside an `INDIRECT` to determine the target range for the array function, what's going on here is actually quite simple; get the `MAX` of `VALUE` of the `MID(3,2)` string of `A` (ignoring errors), add `, and prepend 'FR'. Easy.
3. This formula will work irrespective of sorting and regardless of how many blank rows might be inserted.
4. Thank you to @Hannu for the note on using `TEXT` to handle formatting single-digit outputs. Note that if you use the `TEXT(...,"00")` version, it will break for three-digit outputs; you'll need to adjust to `TEXT(...,"000")` in that case (assuming 'FR001' etc works for single digit outputs!).

Okay, so now you have the value you need, but it's just sitting there. What next?

### Part II

Google "Excel record macro" and read a couple of tutorials. From there it should be pretty easy to complete your task. If you really want to cross your i's and dot your t's, write up your solution as an answer, and after a day or two you can accept your own answer. @ me in the comments and I'll upvote, too. This is a very useful skill and a perfect example use case.

Comment: FWIW: `TEXT(number,"00")` will create double digit numbers for you.

Comment: @AlexM Thanks for all your work on this! That formula is in my worksheet and functioning really well. I'm going to take time next week to dig into the macro/VBA needed to make the numbering scheme function. My goal after that is to automate the numbering process whenever a new row is put in. I'll post back with and update next week.

Comment: @Hannu Nice, can't believe I missed that, thank you very much. Edited answer.

Comment: @Endro recording a macro is only nominally VBA (in that Excel creates a VBA module for you once you're done, but you don't interact directly with VB yourself when recording a macro). Conflating the two may make you feel like creating a macro is a much bigger task than it is. You're really going to love it.